# What to do when the question is marked as off topic?

Tags: discussion

A few months ago, I had a question subject which was like this

> How do i create imageassets for IOS from single png with the JSON file included?

I posted it on the Graphic Design Stack Exchange, and it was flagged as off topic, and I was told that it should rather be posted on the Ask Different Stack Exchange.
So I deleted the post and went to Ask Different and posted it, and there too it was flagged and I was told to post it on Game Development Stack Exchange (the post was about game sprites). 
There too was the same thing happened, it was flagged off topic.
So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're posting questions without checking if they are on-topic for the site, and you rely on the advice of people who have no clue what's on-topic on other sites.

Comment: @Bart but doesn't the question relate to those communities?

Comment: @BhagyeshChaudhari We don't really know, since this is a different community. Ask on the Meta of those sites instead.

Comment: @Stijn  generally speaking, how do i know which community a particular question be asked to ?

Comment: That question might be considered too broad no matter where you post it, if that's all there was to the question.

Answer (score 6):

So what you really want to know is where you *should* post the question.

This question ("Where do I post X?") is something for [Meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com), using the tag "site-recommendation".

You go there, ask where to post it, and give as much details about the question as you have available. The clearer the question, the more likely it is that the community over there can help you find the right SE site.

However, in the end, it will be your own responsibility to make sure that the question is on-topic. So (as @Bart points out in the comments) you should check the Help Center of the site where you intend to post. The "Help" dropdown at the top of every SE site, on the left, takes you there.
If you have 5 points or more on a site, you can also ask on their per-site meta.
If you have 20 or more, you can also check if the site has a chatroom where "can I ask X?" is welcome.

Comment: Also note that before posting, each site has a Help Center stating what is on-topic. And when in doubt, each site has a Meta where you could ask whether or not something is on-topic.

Comment: @Bart Added that.